# I'm saving pictures with camera x. I want to set the resolution to 4000:3000

Tags: android, image, resolution

I'm saving pictures with camera x. I want to set the resolution to 4000:3000 and proceed with the same resolution value, but the resolution is changing differently depending on the device. In this case, do I have to resize the bitmap?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code can help you to set the custom resolution on the configuration of Camera X

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
.setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
.build()
```

You can check out the full article over here [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration)

Comment: I tried it, but it was set up differently depending on the specifications.